# Could not execute system() command in Ruby Controller on remote server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Ruby controller method:

```
def wayback
 $newvar = "wayback_machine_downloader http://example.com"
 system($newvar)
end
```

Now, above controller method runs like a charm locally i.e in `localhost:3000` but when I put my code live in server then `system($newvar)` command does not work. I am using digitalocean server.

Comment: Can you define what "does not work" means for you?  And can you include whatever errors you're seeing in your logs?

Comment: system() command does not work when I put my code live on server. and there are no error log shown on console

Comment: Are you able to log in to the server and execute `wayback_machine_downloader http://example.com` from a shell prompt?

Comment: Yes it is working in SV shell prompt but not working in my controller method :/

Comment: Are you logged into the server as the same user as the application runs on the server?  And are you certain the environments match, especially `$PATH` ?

Comment: I think environments dont match in my case. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use global variables like `$newvar` for no reason. These things can cause complete chaos in your code if you're not aware of what they do. Here `system("...")` is sufficient but you can do one better:

```
system("wayback_machine_downloader", "http://example.com")
```

This avoids any security problems you might have when dealing with unescaped command-line arguments. If you accept user input here imagine what someone could do with `| rm -rf /` as a URL.

If you're having trouble executing, specify the full path to your executable. That avoids dealing with `PATH` issues.

Comment: You'll have to ensure whatever executable is either in your `PATH` or you will need to specify the full path to it.

Answer (score 0):

- First thing you should not be using $ global variables in there.
- Secondly the issue does not seem to be with system() command rather what's inside it. Try instead a simple command to make sure system command works normal or not

  **something like: wget http://example.com**

  If it runs then make sure library wayback_machine_downloader is installed on server as well. In case wget does not work either then share the log errors may be. The easiest way to test and identify issues would be by running below command directly from terminal on your digital ocean server.

  **wayback_machine_downloader http://example.com**

Comment: Thanks Azan bhai! Commands were running perfect in Server console. I have tried everything but no luck.

Comment: This link would help you then! Try a different method other than system command. http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands

Comment: This is great. I will try this.